# Python - ConfigParser - AttributeError: ConfigParser instance has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, ini, configparser

I am creating a quote of the day server. I am reading options from an INI file, whose text is below:

```
[Server]
host =
port = 17

[Quotes]
file=quotes.txt
```

However, when I use ConfigParser, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 59, in <module>
    Start()
  File "server.py", line 55, in Start
    configOptions = parseConfig(filename)
  File "server.py", line 33, in parseConfig
    server = config['Server']
AttributeError: ConfigParser instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from socket import *
from  ConfigParser import *
import sys

class serverConf:
    port = 17
    host = ""
    quotefile = ""

def initConfig(filename):


    config = ConfigParser()

    config['Server'] = {'port': '17', 'host': ''}
    config['Quotes'] = {'file': 'quotes.txt'}

    with open(filename, 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)


def parseConfig(filename):

    configOptions = serverConf()



    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read(filename)

    server = config['Server']

    configOptions.port = int(server['port'])
    configOptions.host = conifg['Server']['host']
    configOptions.quoteFile = config['Quotes']['file']



    print "[Info] Read configuration options"

    return configOptions

def doInitMessage():

    print "Quote Of The Day Server"
    print "-----------------------"
    print "Version 1.0 By Ian Duncan"
    print ""

def Start():

    filename = "qotdconf.ini"
    configOptions = parseConfig(filename)

    print "[Info] Will start server at: " + configOptions.host + ":" + configOptions.port

Start()
```

Why am I getting this error, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Brackets won't work.  Use the `get()` function. 

`configOptions.host = conifg.get('Server','host')`

http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#examples

Comment: Well, you're trying to use `config` as if it were a dictionary, and it's not, it's a `ConfigParser` instance...

Comment: In future, you might want to refer to the [`ConfigParser` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#configparser-objects).

Comment: this solution would work in py3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a quick read it seems like you're trying to read the data as if it's a dictionary, when you should use: `config.get(section, data)`

EG:

```
...
config = ConfigParser()
config.read(filename)
...
configOptions.port = config.getint('Server', 'port')
configOptions.host = config.get('Server', 'host')
configOptions.quoteFile = config.get('Quotes', 'file')
```

To write to the config-file you could do something like:

```
...
def setValue(parser, sect, index, value):
    cfgfile = open(filename, 'w')
    parser.set(sect, index, value)
    parser.write(cfgfile)
    cfgfile.close()
```

Comment: I must have read the guide on some website wrong, because I thought it said to use angle brackets.

Comment: You could use the python docs:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Comment: This is the difference between the python 3 version of configparser and the pyhton 2.7 version of the configparser. in python 3.3, this is what you would normally do.

Comment: this is incredibly annoying since they are named almost identically. my local python2 found configparser and used it without any problems, but it crashed my staging and this took me a while to figure out to rename it to ConfigParser and not use angle brackets.
thanks for the help stackoverflow!

Answer (score 5):

The included `ConfigParser` with python 2.7 does not work in this fashion.   You can, however, achieve exactly what you've proposed using the back ported `configparser` module [available on PyPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configparser).

```
pip install configparser
```

Then you can use it just as you would in Python 3*

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read("settings.ini")
# or parser.read_file(open("settings.ini"))
parser['Server']['port']
# '17'
parser.getint('Server', 'port')
#  17
```

**NOTE**

- `configparser` is not 100% compatible with the Python 3 version.
- The backport is intended to keep 100% compatibility with the vanilla release in Python 3.2+.
- Using it in this fashion displayed above, will default to the Python 3 implementation if available.

Answer (score 0):

for python3
**iniparser.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import configparser
import sys

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(sys.argv[1])
print(config[sys.argv[2]][sys.argv[3]])
```

using

```
python iniparser.py <filepath> <section> <key>
```