# ConfigParser instance has no attribute '[extension]'

Tags: python, configparser

I am learning python and I am trying to do a simple task of reading information from a config file.

So using the [Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#examples) and this [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407329/python-configparser-attributeerror-configparser-instance-has-no-attribute) as a reference I created two files.

This is my config file `config.ini` (also tried `config.cfg`)

```
[DEFAULT]
OutDir = path_to_file/

[AUTH]
TestInt = 100
TestStr = blue
TestParse = blua
```

and this is my python file `test.py`

```
import ConfigParser

from ConfigParser import *
config = ConfigParser()

config.read(config.cfg)

for name in config.options('AUTH'):
    print name

out = config.get('DEFAULT', 'OutDir')
print 'Output directory is ' + out
```

however when running the command `python test.py` I am erroring out and receiving this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    config.read(config.cfg)
AttributeError: ConfigParser instance has no attribute 'cfg'
```

Note: I thought that meant it the extension couldn't be read so I created the `.ini` file and changed it in the code and I received the same error but it instead read `...has no attribute 'ini'`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong since I am doing the exact same as the python doc and the solution someone used to fix this similar issue.

Comment: `"config.cfg"` not `config.cfg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.read` takes a string as its argument. You forgot to quote the file name, and `config` was coincidentally the name of a Python object (the module) that potentially could have a `cfg` attribute. You'd get an entirely different error if you had written `config.read(foobarbaz.ini)`.

The correct line is

```
config.read('config.cfg')  # or 'config.ini', if that's the file name
```

Comment: Sigh. Such a simple mistake that I couldn't see. Thanks. I was chasing down the wrong tail.